# JNI How to generate header (.h) with multipe file java

Tags: java-native-interface

I want to generate header file from 2 class in java example:
File class1.java and File JniTest.java

```
public class class1
{
 /*do something*/
}
public class JniTest
{
 static {
        System.loadLibrary("JniTest");
    }
    private native void testObject(class1 object1);
}
```

When i generate header file using command (java8):

> javac -h . JniTest.java

This is error

```
    JniTest.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        private native void testObject(class1 object1);
                                       ^
      symbol:   class calss1
      location: class JniTest

1 error
```

How to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Are you sure the two .java files are in the same directory and that you typed the name of the class correctly?

Comment: I sure " Are you sure the two .java files are in the same directory and that you typed the name of the class correctly?"

Comment: Even though your pasted error mentions a "calss1"? Show actual code and actual error message then.